# Parse Laravel Variable from Form Field

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

I want to parse variables in voyager admin form field and read it in the blade template.

voyager form field value :

```
LON{{$from}}HER{{$to}}
```

Im setting the "from" and "to" as date values in the template.

I want the end string to be like: "LON0513HER0520"

how can this be done?

my blade template looks like this:

```
@php
  $from = Carbon::today()->addDays(7)->format('md');
  $to = Carbon::today()->addDays(14)->format('md');
@endphp

<a href="https://myurl/flights/{{$slider->button_url}}"</a>
```

form field is called  `button_url` in db and contains: `{{'LON'.$from.'HER'.$to}}`

But im just getting url as a long string: `http://myurl/%7B%7B'LON'.$from.'HER'.$to%7D%7D` when parsed. I need it to be `http://myurl/flights/LON0513HER0520`

Hope this makes sense.

thanks

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? Is it in the parsing or in the producing of the en string ? What have you tried yet ?

Comment: try this {{'LON'.$from.'HER'.$to}}

Comment: @GauravGupta i've added that in the form field but i just get the url as a string. Please see my updated question above,

Comment: try this <a href="https://myurl/flights/"{{$slider->button_url}}></a> also in you "a" tag  ">"  is missing.

Comment: @GauravGupta this is what im doing already.  `<a href="https:/myurl/flights/{{$slider->button_url}}" 
      title="{{ $slider->button_text}}">{{ $slider->button_text}}</a>` but all im getting is the raw form field text and the variable is not rendering. Is there a way to set a variable in form field and call it back in the blade template?

Comment: Try with url encode

Comment: @GauravGupta nope still not joy `{{urlencode($slider->button_one_url)}}` this gives the output as `%7B%7B%24from%7D%7D`

Comment: do this before for a tag {{dd('LON'.$from.'HER'.$to)}}  and check out put @NabiArshad